# how to return char array pointer in c.

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, return

```
char* GetCollection()
{
    FILE *collection;
    char val1[15] = "collection.txt";
    collection = fopen(val1,"r");

    char readingline[10];
    char *listofurls[10];
    *listofurls = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    int j= 0,k,m=0,p, nov=0, q, r;

    while (fscanf(collection, "%s", readingline)==1) {

        listofurls[j] = malloc(10*sizeof(char));

        strcpy(listofurls[j],readingline);

        j++;
        nov++;
        }

    for (k = 0 ; k < nov ; k++)
        printf("%s\n", listofurls[k]);

    fclose(collection);
    return listofurls;
}
```

I want to return listofurls from GetCollection method and use it in main method. I am not able to catch the return value in main method.

Comment: this is plain wrong, you need to alloc a char ** and each char *.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre.: Why do we need to allocated for `char**`? We can simply allocate `char*`'s and then `char`'s and return that `char**`. (If you don't mind me asking)

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya.: No no...I am not saying that. Ofc you don't want to but you can return a `char**` holding the address of the dynamically allocated memory. My answer is what I am trying to mean.

Comment: Why do you want to allocate a fixed size (10 items) in the function and return a pointer to it. The caller can provide this fix sized array and passes the pointer as a parameter to the function. If you need a dynamic size array, an additional parameter suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that - though the memory it points to has lifetime beyond the scope of the function - the array has not. Array is of automatic storage duration. So you can't do that. Trying to access it outside the scope on which it is declared invokes Undefined behavior.

Easy solution, allocate the memory which contains the `char*`s dynamically. (Another would be to wrap the array inside a `struct` and then return it from the function).

```
#define MAXSIZE 10
...
...
char **listofurls;
listofurls = malloc(sizeof *listofurls * MAXSIZE);
if( !listofurls ){
    perror("malloc");
    exit(1);
}
...
return listofurls;
```

In fact it is not clear why you suddenly allocate memory for the `0`th pointer in the array of pointer `listofurls`. There is a memory leak for that. You didn't check the return value of `fopen`. Check whether it is successful in opening the file or not.

And with the changes proposed the signature of the function would be

```
char** GetCollection();
```

With these changes you will hold the return value in `main()`

```
char** p = GetCollection();
```

And along with this you will free this allocated memory when you are done working with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to return an array, you can wrap it in a `struct` like this, but I prefer @coderredoc's `malloc` solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct MyStruct
{
  char* listofurls[10];
};

struct MyStruct GetCollection()
{
    FILE *collection;
    char val1[15] = "collection.txt";
    collection = fopen(val1,"r");
    if (collection == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", val1);
      exit(-1);
    }

    char readingline[10];
    struct MyStruct myStruct;
    int j= 0,k, nov=0;

    while (fscanf(collection, "%s", readingline)==1) {

        myStruct.listofurls[j] = malloc(10);  //sizeof(char) is always 1
        if (myStruct.listofurls[j] == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to malloc for string %d\n", j);
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(myStruct.listofurls[j],readingline);
        }

        j++;
        nov++;
    }

    for (k = 0 ; k < nov ; k++)
        printf("%s\n", myStruct.listofurls[k]);

    fclose(collection);
    return myStruct;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct MyStruct myStruct = GetCollection();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", myStruct.listofurls[i]);
        free(myStruct.listofurls[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And turn on compiler warnings, `-Wall -Wextra` should suffice .. you have several, including trying to return the local array.  Always check the return value of function calls that could return errors (`fopen`, `malloc`)